# Not able to sign into Chat using Firefox 4.0.1

Tags: support, chat, login, firefox

I'm not able to sign into chat using Firefox 4.0.1 on Windows XP. I'm logged in to Super User & Stack Exchange, head over to goto https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access, I get the

> you must be logged in to talk.

link instead of chat box. Click on the link, I get logged in and the message comes - "Welcome Sathya, you're being redirected", redirect back to chat only to see that I am logged out again.

This happens on a fresh install of Firefox 4.0.1, no add ons whatsoever. I can log in to chat using IE7 (!) but I don't want to use it.

Here's what I've done:

- Logged out of Super User
- Logged out of Stack Exchange
- Logged in to Stack Exchange
- Logged in to Super User
- Clicked on the [login to chat link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global?returnurl=https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)
- Used the [fallback login](https://superuser.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login)
- [Global Login Auth Test & Help Page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help) reports "All tests successful"

Comment: I can confirm it's _probably_ not a browser issue. I use FF 4.0.1 on XP and Win7 and both work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We [figured this out in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/920934#920934), for some reason, there were multiple instances of the same cookie in the browser, hence clearing cookies fixed the issues.

Not sure yet if this was a pure browser issue or a (obviously very rare) bug in chat. We'll check.