# Cannot login in skeptics chat with MyOpenID account

Tags: bug, chat, stack-exchange, login, myopenid

I tried to log me in into the skeptics chat, but the site simply
does not accept my login without any error indication, but
redirecting me to the exact same page.

Some specifications:

- Firefox 20.0, Mac 10.8.3 & Windows 7, i5 Core.
- I *can* login in Stackoverflow chat with OpenID. No problem at all.
- Tried and tested every step on the FAQ page.
- Looked up the solutions. The problem is that all of them to have a general
  login problem and for the few where it is not the case it is claimed to be fixed.

Sorry, I am stuck. :(

EDIT:

I was pinged by Sklivzz. I saw the red point indicating a new message and moved to this page:
[image: Chat Reason hub]

If I try to enter with 'You must be "logged in" to talk....' down, I am back on the main page with the URL https://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fchat.stackexchange.com%2frooms%2f311%2fhub-of-reason

[image]

EDIT: I can now log myself in and access the all chats hubs. Thanks !

Comment: Try [clearing your cookies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89658/152859).

Comment: Nope, does not work...

Comment: Any browser extension/plugins/user scripts? If so try to disable them all and see if this help. Also, can you login to chat using different browser?

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting: I *can* log in with Safari, but not with Firefox 20, even now. I use NoScript, but gave it as test full rights.

Comment: @Sklivvz Yes, I received that ping in Firefox.

Comment: What ping.....?

Comment: Sklivvz send a chat message in the skeptics chat and asked "do you receive this ping ?"

Comment: @ThorstenS. can you join the chat by following the link? You have a user there (since you received the ping). Also - what error are you getting?

Comment: I don't believe you.

Comment: @Won't took me a second to get that. Must go get some more coffee :)

Comment: No problem. Tell me just what I can do and I will...

Comment: It works now ! Thanks !